# std in/out/err redirection in sub process of forked process

Tags: c, bash, io-redirection, fork

I'm writing a basic reverse shell in C:

```
if(-1 ==  (myShell->pid = fork()))
{
    PipeSet_close(&myShell->pipeSet);
    return RS_ERROR;
}

if(myShell->pid == 0)
{
    /* close pipe ends child doesn't need */
    close(myShell->pipeSet.stdInPipe[1]);
    close(myShell->pipeSet.stdOutPipe[0]);
    close(myShell->pipeSet.stdErrPipe[0]);

    /* dupe 2 the pipes we DO need frm their originals */
    dup2(myShell->pipeSet.stdInPipe[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(myShell->pipeSet.stdOutPipe[1],fileno(stdout));
    dup2(myShell->pipeSet.stdErrPipe[1],fileno(stderr));

    /* bash now replaces child process. only returns after bash terminates */
    execl(getenv("SHELL"),NULL,NULL);
    return RS_SUCCESS;
}
```

I can read and write from my 3 pipes fine using my parent process. This allows me to execute basic shell commands through the child. ls -l, ps, chmod +x etc. What I'm having issues with is when I use the shell to run a simple program which requires user input. I use the following program to test this:

```
int main()
{
int opt;
while (1==1)
{
    printf("-----Remote Shell Menu test:------\n");
    printf("   1. print 1\n");
    printf("   2. print 2\n");
    printf("   3. exit\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&opt);

    switch (opt)
    {
    case 1: printf("Pressed 1\n"); break;
    case 2: printf("Pressed 2\n"); break;
    case 3: return 0;
    default: printf("unknown menu option %d\n",opt);
    }
}
}
```

I'm able to interact with this sub program as i would normally though my reverse shell, and press "1" "2" 1" "3" but i don't get the menu or see any of the output through my stdout pipe until the entire menu program terminates and i press 3. Can anyone tell me why this is?

This is not the case if a spawn another bash shell from within my forked bash...

Comment: It's because of buffering.  The child most likely line buffers output if stdout is a tty, but block buffers when stdout is a pipe.

Comment: Not entirely related to your issue, but `execl()` *never* returns if it succeeds. If it fails for any reason, it does return, but then you return `RS_SUCCESS`, which might mask something down the road...

Answer (score 1):

You have `fflush(stdin)` which does nothing. fflush is used only on output streams. I believe if you change this to `fflush(stdout)`, it will solve your buffering problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should also `close` the duplicated pipes after `dup2` so that the processes will get a chance to detect EOF.

You may add `perror` after `execl`; better use `execlp`; give an `argv[0]` instead of `NULL`.
What happens if `getenv("SHELL")` is `NULL`? Are you sure it is `bash`?

In main, `return` something; testing `1==1` is useless in `while` (infinite loops are usually obtained with `while(1)` of `for(;;)` )